# The travel of soundwaves

Tags: waves, acoustics, everyday-life

As we are waiting in the subway station, we will hear the rail screeching when the train is arriving. Is it because soundwaves travels faster in a solid substance than in air? or is it a compartment in the rail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of sound in a dense solid such as metal is more than ten times faster than in air. Also, the rail will act as an acoustic [wave guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_(acoustics)). Both of these factors explain why you can hear the sound of an approaching train through the rails before you hear it through the air.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure the OP properly defined the problem.  I read "rail screeching" as the sound, arriving via the air, caused by wheels rubbing against the rails as the train takes a curve.   It's pretty difficult to determine the source of sound in a tube station.  (and the rails themselves, after all, are emitting all along their length)

Answer (score 1):

You don't hear it throught the rails unless you put your ear to the rails and you shouldn't do that. What you hear is the sound propagating through the air. The fact that you hear it before the train arrives is due to the fact that the speed of sound is larger than the speed of the train. The fact that the speed of sound in the solid rail is larger than in air is secondary to this problem.